# absolute position image inside bootstrap thumbnail container image

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am working on bootstrap thumbnail container image, where i need to position the price of the product in bottom right of the image. However, it seems that the approach i use fails when the image size is smaller than the container size.

The absolute positioning currently relative to the outermost div. However, i would like the absolute positioning relative to the image instead.

Note: It is a responsive thumbnail div with fixed size image.

```css
.img-holder {
  position: relative;
}

.price-container {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <div class="img-holder">
        <img src="http://dummyimage.com/330x200/000/fff" alt="...">
        <div class="price-container">
          USD 5.00
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="caption">
        <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
        <p>...</p>
        <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Button</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Button</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `display: inline-block` to `img-holder`

```css
.thumbnail {
   text-align: center;
 }

.img-holder {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}

.img-holder img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.price-container {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: red;
}

.caption {
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <div class="img-holder">
        <img src="http://dummyimage.com/330x200/000/fff" alt="...">
        <div class="price-container">
          USD 5.00
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="caption">
        <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
        <p>...</p>
        <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Button</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Button</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: it works but few bug appears after that. The first one is that image is not being centered, and the second one is that the image size does not fit into the container when image width is more than container width

Comment: @stackdisplay Updated my answer, see if it helps.